# Difference between an array and single-column in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays

For databases that support arrays -- for example, Postgres -- what would be the difference between the following two items:

```
`name`  `field_a` (row array)
Tom      [1, 2, 3]
```

And:

```
`name`   `field_a` (single column)
Tom       1
Tom       2
Tom       3
```

The above would be two 'variations' of combining two tables:

- **name**

  ```
  `name`
   Tom
  ```
- **numbers**

  ```
  `field_a`
  1
  2
  3
  ```

If the array version vs the other version are not interchangeable, what are the main differences between the two?

Comment: They are totally different.  An array is a data structure that describes the data in a single column in a single row.  A column describes data that has a (potentially) different value in every row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yea, maybe it's a poorly worded question -- I updated the sample tables a bit -- does that make it more clear?

Comment: @Chandu thanks. Would you care to post an answer showing the differences?

Answer (score 0):

- `Array` stores the data in a single row and it needs some kind of processing (Different for different databases) before accessing/searching/sorting the particular value. It saves the size of table as repeating data occurs in single row but ultimately had more processing time when it comes to updating/searching/sorting and many more operations on the data stored as array.
- Single values in each row is more preferred in databases as it is easy to find the record, update particular data, sort the data and many more operations.

So according to me only insertion of array is faster than the individual values and it saves some space of the table but all other operations will be time consuming. So it is better to store individual values in each row for database.

Databases are designed to handle single values more easily and operations on single values are faster than the arrays.

Simple **example of complexity** from your question: Replace 2 with 5 in `field_a` for `name = 'Tom'`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking about it is that an array named `column` is effectively `column0`, `column1`, `column2` etc which the DB handles for you, whereas the table is normalized ([1st Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)) into rows.

It is, however, harder to enforce a fixed size array in a normalized structure. You can enforce a maximum by defining a third table with numbers 0,1,2 and foreign-keying the child table on that. You **cannot** enforce a minimum like this (except in certain DBMSs with DB level constraints).

Rarely are fixed size arrays actually necessary. The majority of cases when they are used just break 1st Normal Form